# Is it possible to add a comment with an IP address in a WAF IPSet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

I am curious if it is possible to add a comment so that I know who's IP Address I have in an IPSet in an AWS WAF. I have a list of employees IP addresses and I would like to keep track of who an IP Address belongs to without having to maintain it separately.

I have the IP Addresses added to the list and that works as expected but I have no way of knowing who the IP belongs to without keeping a list on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.

You might be able to use the [description](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-ipset.html#cfn-wafv2-ipset-description) for the IP set (256 character limit) as a small workaround, but there's no 'comment' or 'description' functionality per IP that would be displayed in the console.

You'll have to keep a list yourself e.g. if you're using IaC, this could be as basic as just adding comments in the template/module.